# Syntax-Highlighting in Intellij - Custom Language

Tags: java, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, intellij-plugin

I am currently developing an Intellij-Plugin in Java for a custom language.

Is there any way, that I can **easily** and **through my code** register a file type and keywords for Syntax-Highlighting?

Comment: What do you mean by "programmatically"? Do you mean that the keywords in your language are not fixed?

Comment: I think I chose the wrong word. I mean, that I can set the file type and the keywords by my code.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite understand what you mean. Every custom language plugin defines a file type, associates it with certain file extensions, and defines the keywords for that file type. Are you trying to accomplish something different to that?

Comment: Please also check out the custom language development documentation at http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support.html

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I solved my problem with the custom language development documentation now. I was actually looking for an easier way, to solve Syntax Highlighting, without generating a Lexer and Parser, etc, because I just needed to highlight some keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You can go into file > settings > editor > filetypes

- Create  new file name it however you like; say javascript custom
  fill in the keyword you want highlighted by group (1-4)
  ** note to have it work it you will have to essentially recreate the entire list (which isn't to difficult via internet search for a keyword list)
  Once your happy with the list simply add file name patterns on that file with a wild card *.js (this is the part that will use your custom file over the provided ** easy to go back/edit/delete your own file)

Here's an example I found online [CSS Keyword list example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYfhm.png)